# Who allocates heap to a DLL?

Tags: windows, dll

Suppose I develop a DLL, say 1.dll using MS visual studio 2005/2008, then I link this DLL to a console application, say 1.exe, at load time (using header file and .lib file) then When inside DLL, if I am allocating memory at run time, then who allocates heap (free store) to the DLL.

As I understand that DLL uses process's address space for data, code and stack.

Comment: Who understands this question on StackOverflow?

Comment: @leppie: please see, I have tried to explain and make clear my question.

Comment: @leppie: This question does not deserve negative vote!

Comment: it doesn't say that @leppie downvoted you. but anyway we really don't get what you're talking about.

Comment: @leppie: I couldn't say the question is exactly clear to me either, but I'm trying to answer it on a best-guess basis.

Comment: DLLs do not have stacks. Threads have stacks.

Comment: +1 the english is bad, but the question is good.

Comment: @Chris Becke: could you please rephrase the question in better english? You seem to have understood it better.

Comment: They want to know which freestore manager is responsible for memory allocated by a dll and by implication, how that does not conflict with memory allocated by the exe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you make a Dll - you always write it in some Language - in your case C++ using Visual Studio 2005 or 2008.

In which case it is the C++ runtime that is responsible for creating its freestore and deciding how to allocate it.

Specifically, if you use the Dll runtime option, then a single dll - msvcrtxx.dll - manages a single freestore that is shared between all dll's, and the exe, that are linked against that dll.

If you use the static runtime option when beuiding your exe and dlls, then the exe and each dll gets its own instance of libc built in, with its own freestore management.

Answer (score 4):

When you execute code inside a DLL the code is executed in the context of your process and on the thread that is calling and, in that way, memory is allocated in your process space.

The implementation of the DLL can of course span new threads or new processes. In the latter case the memory allocation will take place in the new forked process.

That means when 1.exe executes the DLL all memory allocated (including the stack) goes to your process memory space (i.e. if the DLL allocates 1 GB of memory then it will reflect in your process memory consumption).

Answer (score -1):

You do the memory management. DLLs have separate heaps, so you need to do the management yourself. Of course, depending on your environment, there may be an specialized new/delete available for your convenience.

There are two types of dynamic memory to handle, *and to keep apart*:

- You can use the calling [process' heap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366569%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), but that will be a different one for every calling process, obviously. So you use that only for data depending on the caller.
- For the memory your DLL uses in general, independent of caller, you'll have to get a separate "private" heap, using [HeapCreate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366599%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and its sibling functions.

Be careful not to pass on the responsibility for that memory to anything else. What your DLL allocates, your DLL will delete - otherwise, you'll get trouble. That should be the basic rules, but over GC some people forget how use memory responsibly, so I mention it.

Comment: What does you here refers to? Who provides heap to a DLL?

Comment: @Vikas: When *you* write the DLL, then it is *your* job to do the memory management.

Comment: Would the downvoter please explain his/her reason?