# Build C++ dll for Release and Debug

Tags: c++, dll

So I'm getting into c++ and I recently built a logger class ie print any type to the screen and/or to a log file. I built it as a dll and the output files are

```
console.h
console.lib
console.dll
```

I then imported these files as additional includes to another project and it works, only in debug mode (in which it was built) I wish for it to work regardless of build config. How can I accomplish this. An example, I recently used the GLFW library and can build in both how was it compiled for this to work.

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio?

Comment: @ZDF yes I am using Visual Studio

Comment: Just change the configuration from debug to release and build. The output is generated in Release sub directory. Both configurations are automatically generated when you create a new project.

Comment: Yes, but will this work if im debugging the application into which this library is included

Comment: Current VC version turns on the debug info for release configuration, too.

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understood you're trying to link same version of your lib/dll with both debug and release configs of your app.

In general case you need two versions of your lib/dll files, debug and release, and link with the one that matches your application configuration, so for debug config of you app link with debug config of your lib/dll, and release with release.

The most possible problem of using mixed configs (like debug dll with release exe) is allocating memory in one domain and releasing it in another.

EDIT:

To elaborate, the problem can be allocating memory in your DLL and releasing it in your EXE, or vise versa. This doesn't work, at least with VS C-Runtime. For more details, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45806858/453271

Comment: Answer appreciated but I built the lib in Release mode and can't run the application in which the lib is included in debug mode. However, libraries such as GLEW / GLFW work in both debug and release with only one library, is there anyway to build a library that can run in both modes

Comment: Do these libraries APIs are designed to allocate and deallocate memory in DLLs? I'm sure they are. You can redesign your API also, e.g. to allocate/deallocate your logger inside you DLL, e.g. by providing `CreateLogger()`/`DestroyLogger()` exported functions. Also for all other exported classes. Edited the answer to provide more details.